# Does element.childNodes[] behave as a link list in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, linked-list

I have an element object and it has some children appended to it via the `appendChild(Node)` method,I know I can access them with `element.childNodes[index]`.

Now if I remove some element from it by selecting them by their id will the element at index `i+1` be  at index `i` if I removed the one at index `i`?

Secondly is there a way to remove the object from the array only by specifying the indices via some built in method to achieve a linked list like behaviour(i mean without having to copy the elements from their index to a prior index when i remove one that was prior to them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes

2) Try [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> a.splice(3, 1)
[3]
> a
[0, 1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Don't know if `Arrays` or `NodeLists` are implemented with linked lists or something else. Depends on the engine I guess.